# ASP.Net Web API HTTP Verb URL not working from REST Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, rest-client

I'm preparing a ASP.Net Web API Projectin visual studio 2013 (.net framework 4.5.2). I'm facing a problem to access HTTP Verb methods from REST Client (Google Chrome Advanced REST Client / Postman / Fiddler). When I run the project and in the browser writing the url "http://localhost:6667/api/products" I can see from the debug that the get method is getting called. But when I type the same url in REST Client (Google Chrome Advanced REST Client / Postman / Fiddler) it shows error connecting to "http://localhost:6667/api/products". Can anyone give a guidance on the solution?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your local IIS Express from anywhere outside of your machine. You'll need a local desktop REST client to test this locally on your development machine.

http://restclient.org/ is a good place to start.